# Replicating $watch functionality inside of the controller with angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a very large site with directives already implemented to standardize some of the buttons on the pages. For this button, the tooltip that appears when hovering over needs to change based on which menu is opened on the screen, which is tracked by bool variables. The tooltip that is passed to the directive is a function that returns a string and I have tried to change this function to return a string based on which bool variable is set and it seems to only set based on the first menu that opens (the button doesn’t appear until a menu is selected). I originally used $watch in the directive to keep track of it but it needs to be done without changing the directive. I’ll include a short code summary of what it is as I cannot copy and paste the code directly. Inside the setToolTip function I’ve tried an if statement as well as $apply and it just doesn’t seem to update the label. I also tried using $apply but it gives errors saying the cycle is already running.

This is the variable passed as information inside of the controller, it has more to it but this is the function that is passed to the directive that controls the tooltip, it seems to run whenever there is a digest cycle but the page is not updated. I have included if statemenrs here I just didn’t want to include them all in this summary.

```
   setToolTip : function () {
      return ‘menu1’
   }
}
```

The directive takes information from another directive, and the label is set from the function passed.

```
label=“{{create.setToolTip()}}”
```

The final directive combines all of the smaller directives into one display of buttons.

```
<action-button create=“ctrl.buttons”>
```

I’ve tried using $apply to run a digest cycle, passing multiple if statements into the label function and other things but can’t get the label to update based on the bool variables set for which menu is open on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure how to troubleshoot your actual question, but FWIW I would consider using $emit and/or $broadcast rather than a $watch for performance reasons